# Не работает CSS псевдокласс :host-context

Tags: css, css3, scss, css-selectors

Никак не могу заставить работать CSS псевдокласс `:host-context`.

Если я верно понял принцип его работы - то нужно просто указать селектор родителя, необходимого для активации указанных стилей, но, видимо, что-то делаю не так. Как заставить демку ниже работать?

В данном примере я хочу добиться того чтобы блоки с классом `.child` меняли свой `background-color` в зависимости от класса родителя. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Спасибо!

```css
.child {
  min-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #232323;
  ;
}

:host-context(.blue-parent) .child {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

:host-context(.green-parent) .child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-parent">
  <div class="child">Должен стать синим</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="green-parent">
  <div class="child">Должен стать зелёным</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()

В документации английским по жёлтому написано, что он работает только в shadow dom.

Comment: Ну и в ваших примерах он вообще  не нужен. Достаточно обычного селектора `.blue-parent .child`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо. Как раз про shadow dom я и упустил момент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все в разы проще, достаточно воспользоваться значением [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inherit):

```css
.blue-parent {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.green-parent {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.child {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-parent">
  <div class="child">Должен стать синим</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="green-parent">
  <div class="child">Должен стать зелёным</div>
</div>
```

*Цитата с [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()) касательно того почему не срабатывает `host-context`:*

> *[host-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()) не имеет влияния когда используется за
> пределами [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)*

---

*Автору вопроса удалось воспользоваться данным свойством на Angular версии 10:*

> Zdarova: Оказалось что `:host-context` в Angular вполне себе работает.

> Vasily: Спасибо за полезную информацию, на какой версии тестировали?

> Zdarova: Тестировал на 10й версии, там завелось.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Вы направили меня в нужную сторону упомянув про shadow dom.И да, конкретно в данном случае подойдёт значение свойства ```inherit```, но мне нужно именно через ```:host-context```, т.к. реальный пример где мне нужно использовать этот селектор более сложный. Он связан с компонентами Angular. Нужно описать отдельные стили для одного компонентка для ситуаций когда этот компонент находится в разных родителях.

Comment: @Zdarova в данном случае разницы быть не должно, Вы также прописываете стили для родителя, а ребенку inherit. Т.е принцип сверху-вниз, если я правильно понял направление из Вашего комментария

Comment: дело в том что компонент должен иметь самые разные свойства, в том числе не наследуемые, например ```margin: 0 auto;``` внутри одного родителя и ```margin: 0;```, если находится внутри другого родителя. Я понимаю что логику центровки можно держать не в этом центрируемом компоненте, а в его родителях. Но текущая задача именно что инкапсулировать такие стили внутри центрируемомго, в данном случае, компонента.

Comment: @Zdarova т.е Вы хотите получить результат "снизу-вверх"?

Comment: Не очень понял что значит результат "снизу-вверх", но в любом случае, спасибо что постарались помочь и, собственно, помогли :) На самом деле проблема уже решена. Оказалось что :host-context в Angular вполне себе работает. Проверил на свежесозданном проекте. А вне ангуляра, как вы и указали, работает только в рамках shadow DOM.

Comment: @Zdarova Рад был помочь) Спасибо за полезную информацию касательно Angular, на какой версии тестировали?

Comment: не за что :) Тестировал на 10й версии) Там завелось)